# Search through items and find which meets the criteria and give back Boolean

Tags: javascript

We have array with objects:

```
 let store =  [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "store1",
          items: {
            pen: 0,
            apple: 1,
            chocolate: 0
          }
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "store2",
          items: {
            pen: 0,
            apple: 0,
            chocolate: 0
          }
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "store3",
          items: {
            pen: 0,
            apple: 1,
            chocolate: 1
          }
        },
      ]
```

and the criteria is: ["apple", "chocolate"].

We have to find the objects where meets the criteria.lenght > 0 and give back a boolean true/false

This is how I tried

```
store.filter(store => criteria.forEach(i => store.items[i] > 0))
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Does each criterion need to be > 0 or just one?

Comment: @NickParsons Expected result is Boolean if its > 0  = true

Comment: [`forEach`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined`. `undefined` is [falsy](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Your [`filter`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will reject everything.

Comment: If you just had `store1` in your array would it be true or false? Ie: chocolate is 0, but apple is 1, so would it be true in this case? Or does it need to be false because there are 0 chocolate and you need all criteria to be > 0?

Comment: @NickParsons it will be true because it meets some of the criteria

Comment: You can use `.some()` for that, but in your question, you say that you "have to find the objects", but then in the comments here you're saying that you need a boolean true/false result.  Do you need the objects that match some of your criteria or just a true/false?

Comment: @NickParsons you are right I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter by checking all criteria with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
const
    stores =  [{ id: 1, name: "store1", items: { pen: 0, apple: 1, chocolate: 0 } }, { id: 2, name: "store2", items: { pen: 0, apple: 0, chocolate: 0 } }, { id: 3, name: "store3", items: { pen: 0, apple: 1, chocolate: 1 } }],
    criteria = ["apple", "chocolate"],
    result = stores.filter(store => 
        criteria.every(criterion => store.items[criterion] > 0)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you want all stores if at least on criterion is true, take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const
    stores =  [{ id: 1, name: "store1", items: { pen: 0, apple: 1, chocolate: 0 } }, { id: 2, name: "store2", items: { pen: 0, apple: 0, chocolate: 0 } }, { id: 3, name: "store3", items: { pen: 0, apple: 1, chocolate: 1 } }],
    criteria = ["apple", "chocolate"],
    result = stores.filter(store => 
        criteria.some(criterion => store.items[criterion] > 0)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: in this case its true when both of the criteria are more then one but in the id: 1 its an apple with 1